# Can I download a copy of a wordpress site to upload onto a new server?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have a website hosted on wordpress.com and I want to move it over onto a godaddy server.

Is there any way for me to transfer everything (theme, customized text, images, etc) over to my new host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can transfer all your posts and images to a new hosting. Sign in to your WordPress.com account and go to your blog’s Dashboard. Click on Export under Tools menu.

Select “All Content” and press the Download Export File button. An XML file will be downloaded in your computer which will contain all of your posts, pages, images, comments, custom fields, categories, tags, navigation menus and other information.

Then To import your old content from WordPress.com to your new site, you need to click on Tools » Import option in your self-hosted WordPress.org dashboard.

More details with images can be found here
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-host-or-server-with-no-downtime/

Answer (score 1):

1)You can donwload you all files from ftp and download database from server or from admin using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-database-backup/

2)And upload files in new server and setup the database and go to the
wp-config.php in root and change the database details

3) Check your .htaccess file

4) Login in admin section and go to the settings tab and change the olde site URL with new one

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that it was hosted on wordpress.com, and they don't give FTP access or anything.